# Converting HTML to ENML

Tags: php, htmlpurifier, evernote

I am trying to write an extension for Gmail that lets you save mail as a note in Evernote, but Evernote's [ENML is pretty strict](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php), as in, it doesn't allow external styles.

So what I am looking to do is something like so -
- convert external styles to inline,
- validate/balance the tags
- purify the tags that Evernote considers offensive

So before I try to jump into writing a parser for above, does anyone know of a php library that is already doing the heavy lifting?

If not, what is the way to go with above requirement?

Comment: The only somewhat interesting "problem" is converting rule-based selector CSS styles into inline styles: "*All* styles must be specified in-line using the 'style' attribute." This is interesting because it requires building the DOM, then applying the rules just as a browser does. The 2nd task can be done with a "lenient" HTML parser (although maybe such invalid input should be immediately rejected?) and the 3rd task can be trivially handled through a DOM walk.

Comment: @user2864740, We can't reject all invalid html, some html mails are so badly written, w3c would jump off a tall building if they see (;

And the CSS parsing would involve replacing all `class="blah"` stuff to `style="blah;blah;"` !! I am hopeful I will find something online

Comment: ENL is not HTML: not all invalid HTML has a valid XML/ENL transformation (although a lenient HTML processor will end up with a DOM; the DOM can never contain mismatched tags so the problem of "fixing" the markup is left to the external HTML library that generates such DOM). And yes, as discussed above, the transformation to inline-style CSS is the only interesting "problem".

Answer (score 1):

If the only interesting problem is **converting external styles to inline styles** you can use https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles. It also has a [composer package at packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles) for easy deployment.

I used it like this:

```
<?php

// ...

use \TijsVerkoyen\CssToInlineStyles\CssToInlineStyles;

// ...

$css = file_get_contents('./content.html');

// create instance
$cssToInlineStyles = new CssToInlineStyles();
$css = file_get_contents('./styles.css');

$cssToInlineStyles->setHTML($content);
$cssToInlineStyles->setCSS($css);

$mail_content = $cssToInlineStyles->convert();
```

Comment: Useful man, thanks!!! I did solve the other problems quite easily, so only this one was remaining!